# Is it possible to count time with Siri?

Tags: siri

I'd like to be able to ask Siri:

> Start counting time
>
> [Some time later] Tell me how long it was?
>
> Siri: It has been 2 minutes and 10 seconds

or

> Tell me the time with seconds
>
> Siri: The time is 3:19, 23 seconds

Any of the above, or any way to count the duration, can work.  Is there a way?

Comment: You can ask to start a stopwatch/read it out. Not sure that's the same thing you want to achieve though. Don't think that's possible.

Comment: yeah, some of my friends are crazy about "AI" and think it is about the whole future. Yet, we can't even do really simple things such as asking Siri to time some short duration for us, which a 10 year old can readily do

Comment: You could do it with SiriKit if you really wanted to, but that would be a stupidly massive thing to do with something so small, there might be an app out there that uses siri to do that type of thing?

Comment: yeah I'd imagine... something so small, it'd be so massively stupid because who really needs to count time, some people may think

Answer (score 1):

This just worked for me on my iPhone 11 with current iOS.

1. Hold side button to invoke Siri
2. Say, "start timer for 15 seconds."
3. Timer starts immediatly counting down.

You have to be a little clever to work around the limitations of the voice interface. After all we are not at the point of the computers on Star Trek. Yet.

So for your particular use case, perhaps a command like, "Siri, start timer for an hour." and a bit later you can do something like, "Siri, stop timer."

It requires you to think like how would you tell Siri to do something that you could also do on the phone through a series of taps. And often it will take a few tries to get the phrasing correct, but once you get the hang of it you will learn how to ask a question of Siri that will give you the answer you need in as few words as possible. Kind of like programming the phone with voice.

Comment: no it is not to count down 15 seconds.  It is to count how long.

Comment: Don't take it so literally, 15 seconds was an example. you could use 15 minutes or 15 hours, or any other length of time. The idea here is to use a time that is way longer than what you think you will need. So that you can refer to the timer for how long something is taking. "How Long" is likely not in Siri's vocabulary, but timing something **IS.** Sometimes you have to use a work-around till technology catches up with real life.

Comment: I need to count from 0 to the end, not some number down to 0. But I guess your hack works somehow if I know it will be a few minutes of duration, but saying "count down for an hour"... except... "Siri, stop timer" does nothing, but "Hey Siri, stop the timer" resets the timer back to 1:00:00... so nothing was measured.

Comment: So essentially open the stopwatch and start it via Siri. Which, strangely enough, seems to be quite impossible. At least in my investigations. If you say, "Siri, start the stopwatch." It brings the stopwatch app up and allows you to tap on start, but it won't start it. And a bit of googling revealed no technique for doing so. A couple of Reddit threads suggest it cant be done. I can certainly see how this would be handy but the Siri/iOS people at Apple must disagree for some reason.