# How to make iPhone/Siri start timing?

Tags: iphone, ios, siri, automation

I want to start a stopwatch to time how long something takes. There are many posts on count down timers (a.k.a egg timer) but none cover a way to start a count-up timer (a.k.a stopwatch) using Siri voice command.

I suspect not, based on all answers [to this related question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/393606/is-it-possible-to-count-time-with-siri) don’t answer the core question of **automation + count up**.

- I prefer to not jailbreak the OS
- Native solution is preferred
- I’m open to third party apps if needed
- I’m open to python or other scripting language or framework if that is “the only way”

Is there any way to achieve this, perhaps via [scriptable](https://apps.apple.com/us/app/scriptable/id1405459188)?

Comment: Hi Steve. Everyone is jumping on the count down timer and I read this the same initially. I hope the massive edit is what you need and you don’t want to start a proxy count down timer and then subtract times to get your interval. Can you clarify if you need simply to start the count up and then will tap to see the result when you’re done timing?

Comment: @bmike thanks very much, you nailed it

Answer (score 1):

To start a countdown timer, simply say: "Hey Siri, set a timer for [hours][minutes][seconds]"

Example: *Hey Siri, set a timer for three hours, 12 minutes and 52 seconds.*

The upper limit on timers is 24 hours, and you can have only one timer running on iPhone (HomePod allows multiple named count down timers now).

- You can ask Siri how much time is left on the timer by asking *Hey Siri, how much time is left on the timer?*
- You can stop the timer by saying *Hey Siri, stop the timer.*

There's no native way for Siri to start a stopwatch / count up timer, unfortunately, except through the UI.

Comment: I agree with this answer, in general you can use shortcuts to make any shortcut that app enabled get a custom siri trigger, but there is no need for custom to set or request timer status. Apple provides that with iOS updates. I’ll see if I can find a workflow to automate this as an edit or different answer…